# How to specify port for PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, ado.net, localhost, port

I am lost. I have localhost database (PostgreSQL) and I have to add port for connection (in app.config -- connection string). I alredy tried:

```
localhost:port
localhost,port
(localhost),port
(local),port
```

None of this work, everytime I got error "The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found" thrown by System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName with message "cannot open connection".

**So how do you specify the port?** I checked this on computer with just single instance of DB server, so port could be ommitted and then it works. But I need adding port.

#### Update

```
<add key="ConnectionString" value="Server=localhost;
 Port=5434;
 Database=XXXXXXX;Initial Catalog=XXXXXXXXX;
 UserID=XXXXX;Password=XXXXX;Encoding=UNICODE;" />
```

Now it works with both "localhost" and "127.0.0.1" (direct IP).

Comment: What's the full connection string you're using? `Server=127.0.0.1;Port=...;User Id=...;Password=...;Database=...;` works for me with PostgreSQL on a non-standard port.

Comment: @pjumble, now it works. With separated Port (with keyword) works! Could you please post your comment as answer so I could accept it?

Comment: posted an answer as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a separate keyword for the port:

```
Server=127.0.0.1;Port=...;User Id=...;Password=...;Database=...;
```